# Mutual Authentication Protocol based on MAC & shared secret key

Tags: protocols

I am quite unsure about how to approach this question, was wondering if anyone could give me a nudge in the right direction, I would be most appreciative!

So I've learned about the 4-way handshake mutual authentication protocol that's based on a shared secret and given secure private-key encryption scheme, but now I need to know this:

Suppose you are given a secure MAC, Describe a similar mutual authetnication protocol based on a shared secret and then given MAC, explain why it is secure.

Comment: Do you mean MAC as in MAC address, or MAC is in mandatory access control? Or some other definition of MAC?

Comment: Mandatory access control, sorry for confusion!

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean "MAC" as Message Authentication Code, such as HMAC?